# CASE expression with OR AND

Tags: case

I have 5 columns - Order, shipping, tracking, Delivery and Overallstauts.

I have have 4 status, Green means "good", Amber means "ok", Yellow means "average" and Red means "Bad".

I want worst status to be displayed in Overallstatus column out of all the status.

| Product | Order | shipping | tracking | Delivery | Overallstatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product1 | Green | Yellow | Green | Red | RED |
| Product2 | Green | Green | Yellow | Green | Yellow |
| Product3 | Yellow | Yellow | Green | Green | Yellow |
| Product3 | Amber | Green | Green | Green | Amber |

I want this in CASE statement

```
Case
When Order = Green, shipping  = Yellow, tracking = Green, Delivery  = Red then Overallstaus  = Red
When Order = Amber, shipping  = Yellow, tracking = Green, Delivery  = Green then Overallstaus  = Yellow
When Order = Yellow, shipping  = Yellow, tracking = Green, Delivery  = Red then Overallstaus  = Red
When Order = Amber, shipping  = Green, tracking = Green, Delivery  = Green then Overallstaus  = Amber
```

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is if you stored the Status names in your columns in a separate Statuses "enums" table, that stored the IDs in increasing order from best to worst then you can do something like the following depending on what database system you're using (T-SQL):

```
SELECT 
    (
        SELECT MAX(OverallStatusId)
        FROM 
        (
            VALUES (OrderStatusId),. 
                (ShippingStatusId),. 
                (TrackingStatusId), 
                (DeliveryStatusId)
        ) AS OverallStatus(OverallStatusId)
    ) AS OverallStatusId
FROM OrdersTable
```

Then all you'd have to do is join to your Statuses enums table on the OverallStatusId above to get the Status name.

Answer (score 1):

If DBMS is MySQL you may use

```sql
SELECT *,
       FIELD(GREATEST(FIND_IN_SET(order, 'Green,Amber,Yellow,Red'),
                      FIND_IN_SET(shipping, 'Green,Amber,Yellow,Red'),
                      FIND_IN_SET(tracking, 'Green,Amber,Yellow,Red'),
                      FIND_IN_SET(delivery, 'Green,Amber,Yellow,Red')),
             'Green', 'Amber', 'Yellow', 'Red') Overallstatus
FROM source_table
```

But I strongly recommend to normalize your data.

Answer (score 0):

If standard SQL you will have to write out each condition. But you can't combine them with `,` in the WHEN clause. Presumably you want to combine them using `AND`. String constants also need to be enclosed in single quotes. `Red` refers to a column, `'Red'` is a character/string constant.

As the CASE is a single expression that returns a single value, the alias for that, needs to be written after the END

```
case
  When Order = 'Green'  and shipping = 'Yellow' and tracking = 'Green' and Delivery  = 'Red'   then 'Red'
  When Order = 'Amber'  and shipping = 'Yellow' and tracking = 'Green' and Delivery  = 'Green' then 'Yellow' 
  When Order = 'Yellow' and shipping = 'Yellow' and tracking = 'Green' and Delivery  = 'Red'   then 'Red'
  When Order = 'Amber'  and shipping = 'Green'  and tracking = 'Green' and Delivery  = 'Green' then 'Amber'
  else 'Unknown'
end as overallstatus
```

Alternatively you could use a tuple comparison:

```
case
  When (Order, shipping, tracking, delivery) = ('Green', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Red')   then 'Red'
  When (Order, shipping, tracking, delivery) = ('Amber', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Green') then 'Yellow'
  When (Order, shipping, tracking, delivery) = ('Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Red')  then 'Red'
  When (Order, shipping, tracking, delivery) = ('Amber', 'Green',  'Green', 'Green') then 'Amber'
  else 'Unknown'
end as overallstatus
```

Or, if your DBMS supports it, a "switched" CASE using tuples:

```
case (Order, shipping, tracking, delivery)
  When ('Green', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Red')   then 'Red'
  When ('Amber', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Green') then 'Yellow'
  When ('Yellow', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Red')   then 'Red'
  When ('Amber', 'Green',  'Green', 'Green') then 'Amber'
  else 'Unknown'
end as overallstatus
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the case expression like this

```sql
SELECT Product, [Order], shipping, tracking, Delivery,
 CASE WHEN [Order] = 'Red'    OR shipping = 'Red'    OR [tracking] = 'Red'    OR Delivery = 'Red'    THEN 'Red'
      WHEN [Order] = 'Yellow' OR shipping = 'Yellow' OR [tracking] = 'Yellow' OR Delivery = 'Yellow' THEN 'Yellow'
      WHEN [Order] = 'Amber'  OR shipping = 'Amber'  OR [tracking] = 'Amber'  OR Delivery = 'Amber'  THEN 'Amber'
 ELSE 'Green'
 END AS Overallstatus
FROM MyTable
```

Note that `Order` is a reserved word. Even `tracking` might be, depending on the SQL dialect (which you didn't tell us). Therefore I escaped it (for TSQL or JetEngine). For Oracle that would be `"Order"` etc.